# Eclipse - how to use Mac OS X (Xcode) toolchain in Eclipse?

Tags: xcode, eclipse, gcc, toolchain

I installed Eclipse (*Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: Juno Release Build id: 20120614-1722*) today.  And I wanted to use the Mac OS X toolchain that is provided with Xcode.  I am running OS X (10.7.4) Xcode 4.3.2, and I checked, and I do have `Command Line Tools` installed.  When I go to Eclipse -> Preferences -> New CDT Project Wizard -> Toolchains: all I see is `GNU Autotools Toolchain`  I don't see the "Mac OS X GCC toolchain".
How do I get the Mac OS X GCC toolchain to appear in the toolchain selection in Eclipse?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found that I sometimes have to uncheck that checkbox at the bottom "Show Project types and toolchains only if they are supported on the platform" Then when I open the Executable folder I can select the MacOs X GCC toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting the GNU Autotools Folder like in your picture above, Select the executable folder and the options for cross gcc and Macosx gcc toolchains should be there.